# Adding elements into view list via edit text field

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to make a edit text field where i enter a string and then by pressing the button beside it this string is added into a list view on a fragment.
When i compile the code i get the following error:

```
10-19 15:04:14.620  21147-21147/com.example.gasper.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.gasper.test.TopRatedFragment.onCreateView(TopRatedFragment.java:57)
```

this is the line 57

```
b.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Does anybody now what is wrong here? I am a beginer in android development so dont judge me :)

I also tried somethong like this but still not working:

```
if(listener !=null){
        b.setOnClickListener(listener);}

package com.example.gasper.test;
```

Here is the full code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.gasper.test.R.layout.fragment_top_rated;

public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment {


    String[] myString =new String[]        {"0ne","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve"};
    List list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(fragment_top_rated, container, false);


        for(String activity : myString){
            list.add(activity);
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),      fragment_top_rated,R.id.textView,list);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        Button b = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText edit = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText);
                list.add(edit.getText().toString());
                edit.setText("");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };


        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_top_rated);
        b.setOnClickListener(listener);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Here is the fragment_top:rated.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffefe4fa" >


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText" />



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick=""/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why u r using getActivity() to get button view..use rootview.findViewById()

Comment: Beacuse rootView would be called within inner class and therefore should be final. I also tried declaring rootView final but that doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: You're doing some pretty weird stuff in your code. First you inflate the fragment then you try to `setContentView` for your activity. Read on some examples first...

Comment: I created fragment(there are 2 more fragment in the app) based on tutorial and then i tried to create listview with text input on one of fragments. Before i added button and onClickListener evrything was working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this line of your code

```
 Button b = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
```

with this line and give it a try

```
Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Edit 1:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),      fragment_top_rated,R.id.textView,list);
```

this line of code shows you are using same xml...is there any textView defined in your this xml..just create a new xml for your list view..and use it here..

Comment: @Gasper Romih try this

Comment: Did that and there is another error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07003c (com.example.gasper.test:id/pager) for fragment GamesFragment{426229d0 #1 id=0x7f07003c android:switcher:2131165244:1}

Comment: i did problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you mistyped the id:

```
Button b = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Your layout has `button1` not `button`.

Edit:

Also the button is found in your fragment's layout not your activity's, so look for it there like this:

```
Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Comment: I just saw that and fix this but the same error is stil here

Comment: I did that and there goes another error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07003c (com.example.gasper.test:id/pager) for fragment GamesFragment{426229d0 #1 id=0x7f07003c android:switcher:2131165244:1}

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayAdapter` has a an internal `List` of its own. The strings `list` you pass to its constructor is merely copied to the internal list to initialize the adapter.

User adapter object's `add()` or `addAll()` to actually add items to `ArrayAdapter`.

Change

```
list.add(edit.getText().toString());
```

to

```
adapter.add(edit.getText().toString());
```

Update 1:

```
Button b = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
```

You are using a fragment and its not yet attached to activity, so activity can't find anything from a view that's not attached to it:

```
Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Comment: thanks for the help but even now there is the same error

Comment: i did that and run again and there is another error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07003c (com.example.gasper.test:id/pager) for fragment GamesFragment{426229d0 #1 id=0x7f07003c android:switcher:2131165244:1}